# Maping the domain name purchased from big rock to aws ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, domain-name

My question is that can i use the default name servers provided by the bigrock for mapping my domain to aws ec2 . 
I have done this by amzon route 53 there i have created a hosting zone and i haved mapped my domain. But aws is charging me around 55rs per month for this.

So can i use the default name servers provided by bigrock and create a A record in bigrock itself. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but it seems that:

- You have purchased a domain name on bigrock.in
- You want to point the domain name to an Amazon EC2 instance

If so, you should do the following:

- In the Amazon EC2 management console, create an **Elastic IP address** and associated it with the EC2 instance. This will give the instance a static IP address that does not change.
- In Big Rock, add an `A-Record` that points to that IP address

There is **no need to use Amazon Route 53** if you do this configuration in Big Rock.

Comment: Ok sir thank you i just want to know that can i use the default name servers provided by bigrock.

Comment: What actually i have done is that i have created a hosted zone in aws 53 and there aws has provided the name servers i have used that name servers for that aws are charging me. So instead of nameservers provided by aws can i use the default name servers provided by bigrock itself

Comment: Yes. There is no need to use Amazon Route 53 if Big Rock is managing your DNS name.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Can we do the same if a static website is hosted on S3 ? I was not able to find a way to assign an Elastic IP to an S3 bucket.

Comment: @Shrinath No, the process for Amazon S3 is different: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)